# Strings: How to combine first and last names in a long text string with other words?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, algorithm, substring

**Problem:**

I have a given string = "Hello @User Name and hello again @Full Name and this works"

**Desired output:** = ["@User Name, @Full Name"]

Code I have in Swift:

```
let commentString = "Hello @User Name and hello again @Full Name and this works"
      let words = commentString.components(separatedBy: " ")
      let mentionQuery = "@"
      
      for word in words.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(mentionQuery) }) {
        print(word) = prints out each single name word "@User" and "@Full"
      }
```

Trying this:

```
if words.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(mentionQuery) }).isNotEmpty {
        print(words) ["Hello", "@User", "Name".. etc.]
      }
```

I'm stuck on how to get an array of strings with the full name = ["@User Name", "@Full Name"]

Would you know how?

Comment: A regex is simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `.filter` means that check each value in the array which condition you given and if true then take value - which not fit here.

For the problem, it can divide into two task: Separate string into substring by " " ( which you have done); and combine 2 substring which starts with prefix "@"

Code will be like this

```swift
let commentString = "Hello @User Name and hello again @Full Name"
let words = commentString.components(separatedBy: " ")
let mentionQuery = "@"

var result : [String] = []
var i = 0
while i < words.count {
    if words[i].hasPrefix(mentionQuery) {
        result.append(words[i] + " " + words[i + 1])
        i += 2
        continue
    }
    i += 1
}
```

The result

```swift
print("result: ", result) // ["@User Name", "@Full Name"]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!  that second step to divide the problem and combine 2 substrings which start with prefix "@" couldn't see it in code.  This works great, I'll study this more, thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter`, like this below:

```swift
let str = "Hello @User Name and hello again @Full Name"
let res = str.components(separatedBy: " ").filter({$0.hasPrefix("@")})
print(res)
// ["@User", "@Full"]
```